Is simple sound transmission in matter normally 100% efficient or is there "leakage" to heat even when there is no damage or destruction of medium
Specifically I was wondering for instance in a perfect gas or real gas or water or steel does the medium absorb some sound as perhaps thermal energy, or can it always travel without losses through the perfect zones of the matter structure.?

Normally nothing is 100% efficient.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161308/are-sound-waves-adiabatic-or-isothermal#:~:text=Sound%20is%20not%20isothermal%2C%20the%20pressure%20disturbances%20induce%20temperature%20oscillations.

This beautifully written article by Finn goes into a lot of the historical details, on top of the physics, but even here, there is no consideration of the fact that there will actually be a bit of losses. However, by having temperature differences, then you can consider the transmissions and thus losses, so it is a great primer.
https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/finn1964.pdf

All ordinary engineering materials contain internal friction mechanisms which will dissipate sound waves traveling through them. Search on "internal friction" for the details.
